# Linking problems on windows (boost)

Tags: boost, shared-libraries, dynamic-linking, static-linking

I'm trying to compile boost and mongodb.

I want 64bit versions, shared libs and dynamic linking to the runtime.

Boost is compiled with `link=shared, runtime-link=shared, threading=multi` (and some others). The lib and dll files have names like: boost_*-vc90-mt-1_41.dll

Now mongodb has per default set: /MT (multithreaded static). The linker required boost libraries with `libboost_*-vc90-mt-s-1_41.dll` (notice the additional `lib` and `-s`). So I changed the option to `/MD` (multithreaded dll) and the `-s`dissapeared but the `lib`stayed. I tried it with `/DBOOST_THREAD_USE_DLL /DBOOST_ALL_DYN_LINK` but it doesn't change. Does the linker still look for the static libs?

Please help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`BOOST_ALL_DYN_LINK` should have done the trick. Please make sure you rebuild your project from scratch, though.

If the problem still persist, I guess you need to tell what is hiding behind the asterisk -- maybe there's a bug with a specific library.

Comment: Basically this did the trick. (I also had to link boost-date_time manually to boost-thread. And some more tweaks in the mongodb scons file...)